# Views 'OR' Operator acting as an 'AND'

Tags: views

This should be very easy, but I cannot figure out why this is not working?

- I have 2 different content types: Type1 & Type2
- I currently have a view which displays all nodes of content Type1.
- I would then like to manually add specific occurrences of Type2.
- So far, I have done this with a Taxonomy term reference field called TaxType (terms: Tax1 & Tax2)

I have set the view to filter by content Type1, which displays all fine.
I then add filter for the Taxonomy Field with the operator of 'OR' but as soon as I add this, it stops showing content Type1?

I would expect this to happen if I left the operator as 'AND'. But with 'OR' it should keep showing Type1 or any occurrences of Tax2.

Drupal 7
Views 3.11

Comment: It would help if you post a screenshot of your filter setup.

Comment: `"I have set the view to filter by content Type1"` then Content Type2 will never show up. You need to allow content type2 here aswell. Then you would need a relationship or a contextual filter, which would filter stuff so it only shows the specific occurrences of Type2

Comment: Can you clarify what are the specific occurrences of Type2? is it show only if they have a certain Tax term?

Comment: ![Screen Shot](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=80899e9).

Comment: @NoSssweat - But they are set up as OR filters. So Type 1 OR Tax 2

Comment: @NoSssweat - For you second comment - Yes. Showing all content that is Type1 and all content (regardless of type) with Taxonomy Term Tax2

Comment: So I am looking to display all content of Type 1 plus also any other content of any type by manual selection

Comment: I have also tried filter "Type1" OR "Any Type + Tax2" which still does not work?

Comment: Solved: Use "Content: Course Type:delta"
What is the Delta for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i can help you out with out a screenshot cause i'm also new to Drupal. But my guess is the filters work in a different way from what you think. It might be something like this...

> Type1 AND (TAX2 OR xxx OR yyy .. etc.)

Hope this helps. Cheers!